# php laravel Get data from db by past week

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am trying to get data from db into a single array

This is what i have tried the foreach loops through all the date of the days of the 1st week and excute this query everytime to get data

```
foreach ($list1 as &$day){
           $pleads = \DB::table('leads')
            ->selectRaw('count(*)') 
            ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id')
            ->where('lead_source_id', 7)
            ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

            $mleads = \DB::table('leads')
                    ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                    ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id')
                    ->where('lead_source_id', 3)
                    ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

            $aleads = \DB::table('leads')
                    ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                    ->whereColumn('owned_by_id', 'users.id')
                    ->where('lead_source_id', 4)
                    ->whereRaw("DATE(created_at) = '$day'");

            $personalleads = \DB::table('users') 
                    ->where('id', $id) // User ID
                    ->select('users.id')
                    ->selectSub($pleads, 'pleads')
                    ->selectSub($mleads, 'mleads')
                    ->selectSub($aleads, 'aleads')
                    ->get();
                    return $personalleads;
                     }
```

when i do this i get only 1 output ex:

```
[{"userid":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1}]
```

but what i want as result is below

```
[{"userid":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":1,"aleads":1},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":1,"mleads":0,"aleads":0},{"userid":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0}]
```

but i think they are multiple objects i can't get them into single array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the loop on first iteration. Instead, store the results in an array, and return outside of loop.

```
$results = [];
foreach ($list1 as &$day){
    $personalleads = ....
    array_push($results, personalleads);
}
return $results;
```

Comment: Thank you very much but i get output like this 
``
[[{"id":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":2,"aleads":1,"totalLead":5,"listingOnCRM":0,"followUpOnCRM":0,"numberOfDeals":0,"numberOfSales":0}],[{"id":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0,"totalLead":0,"listingOnCRM":0,"followUpOnCRM":0,"numberOfDeals":0,"numberOfSales":0}]]
`` i can't parse this using jQuery how to make them in  a single array ? Like

Comment: ``
[{"id":1,"pleads":2,"mleads":2,"aleads":1,"totalLead":5,"listingOnCRM":0,"followUpOnCRM":0,"numberOfDeals":0,"numberOfSales":0},[{"id":1,"pleads":0,"mleads":0,"aleads":0,"totalLead":0,"listingOnCRM":0,"followUpOnCRM":0,"numberOfDeals":0,"numberOfSales":0}]``